# what is the difference b/w css-vertical and css-horizantal menu?

Tags: css

i want to know that what is the difference in css properties of LI and UL that makes a menu vertical and horizantal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vertical would be the default.

For positioning of `li`'s horizontally you would set them to either `float` or `display: inline`.

However if you want to go the `display: inline` route keep in mind that inline elements cannot have a set size.

There is also `display: inline-block`, but I don't think IE supports it.

Comment: are you want to say that float and display:inline makes vertical and horizantal menu?

Comment: Lists are vertical by default, and adding a float (left or right, naturally left) or `display: inline`, would render the list horizontally.